# Inline LINQ Comments in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, linq

Is there some way to insert inline code comments in LINQ in VB.NET?

Please see line 2 in the below as an example of where an inline comment would be desirable

```
Dim Jobs = (From X In DB.Jobs_Select(SearchStr, RequiresFilter)
    Where X.JobStatusID < 2   -- **** INSERT INLINE COMMENT HERE  ****
    Order By
        X.JobPriorityID Descending,
        If(X.TargetDate, Date.MaxValue),
        X.NeedsLit Descending,
        X.HasOldArtRequests Descending,
        X.HasOldLicRequests Descending
    )
```

This is trivial in SQL code and frankly, very useful as SP's become complex. It would be nice to be able to perform the same cross-developer communication in LINQ to SQL.

## Update

Here is a test condition for you.

```
 Dim L As New List(Of KeyValuePair(Of Integer, Integer))

 Dim a = (From X In L
            Where X.Key > 5 'test comment
            Order By X.Value)
```

Comment: Nope, 15 compile errors by inserting an apostrophe at that location

Comment: @BrianWebster: Works for me on a lighter query. Can you update the question with something we can paste into VS to test?

Comment: Uh... VB.NET is really an amazing language. Every time I think I know all its flaws, I discover a new one!

Comment: @ThomasLevesque: don't start on this one. C# is not perfect either.

Comment: If your code needs inline comments, your putting too much in one query, you can always chain separate parts of a query which makes it also easier to read..

Comment: @Neolisk I have pasted a test code block for you

Comment: @Neolisk, don't worry, I'm not going to start a flame war between VB and C#... it's just a bit of harmless teasing ;)

Comment: @Neolist don't start on that one either. Language wars don't belong on SO. (If anywhere outside college.)

Comment: @Andrew Morton Do you have a better suggestion on telling the OrderBy clause that null dates should come last? Otherwise, it gets evaluated as 1/1/0001. I'm open to suggestions. Would appreciate an alternative if you've got gripes

Comment: @BrianWebster: what about Date.MaxValue?

Comment: @Nelisk Did not know of this. Thanks! I will use it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok folks, here is the official answer - not possible in VB. [Proof](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/659633/inline-comments-for-vb-net).

> It is REALLY annoying in VB that you cannot add inline comments to
>   multiline LINQ statements!

And more information:

> The bad news is that this wouldn't be trivial to implement.
>   Limitations about single-lines and comments are built into the current
>   VB parser at too low a level. It'd require a complete rewrite of the
>   VB parser.
>
> The good news is that we've embarked upon such a rewrite (codenamed
>   "Roslyn" -- there have been several articles and talks about it). It's
>   still a way off and we're not making commitments about what/when at
>   this stage.
>
> -- Lucian Wischik, VB language PM

Comment: I found that too tim. Edited it into Neo's answer 3 min ago. Not want I wanted to learn, ultimately, but it's good info.

Comment: @BrianWebster: you are welcome! Hope Roslyn brings some parity between .NET languages.

Answer (score 1):

VB.NET 14 introduced the ability to make inline comments ([link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/we86c8x2.aspx)).

> You can put comments after implicit line continuations, inside initializer expressions, and amongst LINQ expression terms.

Answer (score 0):

If

```
Where X.JobStatusID < 2   ' **** INSERT INLINE COMMENT HERE  ****
```

doesn't work, then it's not possible.

Comment: This does not work in VS2010. It only works if placed after the LINQ statement is terminated, but that is why I'm asking about inline comments

Comment: Wow. Didn't expect that from VB.

Comment: Why the downvote? It's basically the same as the other answer?

Comment: @Alex: don't worry, I just gave you the upvote! I believe you should not be downvoted for trying to help. :)